# Predefined Software installation inputs using Here document

Tags: linux, shell-script, here-document

I want to install software on a CentOS machine and I want to automate the inputs requested by the installation process:

I am trying using heredoc but seems not working.

using something like this script, for example:

```
installation script path << EOF
yes
no
yes
no
EOF
```

any recommendations to solve my problem, please?

Comment: You need to include the contents of the script in the question. Please edit to add information.

Comment: ./MySoftware.bin << EOF ... It is binary file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADD **#!/bin/bash**

The script should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
installation script path << EOF
yes
no
yes
no
EOF
```